# Creating Pandas Dataframe between two Numpy arrays, then draw scatter plot

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scatter

I'm relatively new with numpy and pandas (I'm an experimental physicist so I've been using ROOT for years...).
A common plot in ROOT is a 2D scatter plot where, given a list of x- and y- values, makes a "heatmap" type scatter plot of one variable versus the other.

How is this best accomplished with numpy and Pandas? I'm trying to use the `Dataframe.plot()` function, but I'm struggling to even create the Dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = np.random.randn(1,5)
y = np.sin(x)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

First off, this dataframe has shape (1,2), but I would like it to have shape (5,2).
If I can get the dataframe the right shape, I'm sure I can figure out the `DataFrame.plot()` function to draw what I want.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

There are a number of ways to create DataFrames. Given 1-dimensional column vectors, you can create a DataFrame by passing it a dict whose keys are column names and whose values are the 1-dimensional column vectors:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = np.random.randn(5)
y = np.sin(x)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
df.plot('x', 'y', kind='scatter')
```

Answer (score 10):

Complementing, you can use *pandas* ***Series***, but the *DataFrame* must have been created.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
y = np.sin(x)

#df = pd.DataFrame()
#df['X'] = pd.Series(x)
#df['Y'] = pd.Series(y)

# You can MIX
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':x})
df['Y'] = pd.Series(y) 

df.plot('X', 'Y', kind='scatter')
```

This is another way that might help

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
y = np.sin(x)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.column_stack((x,y)),columns=['X','Y'])
```

And also, I find the examples from [karlijn (DatacCamp)](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-tutorial-dataframe-python) very helpful

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

TAB = np.array([[''     ,'Col1','Col2'],
                 ['Row1' ,   1  ,   2  ],
                 ['Row2' ,   3  ,   4  ],
                 ['Row3' ,   5 ,   6  ]])

dados = TAB[1:,1:]
linhas = TAB[1:,0]
colunas = TAB[0,1:]

DF = pd.DataFrame(
    data=dados,
    index=linhas,
    columns=colunas
)

print('\nDataFrame:', DF)
```

Answer (score 7):

In order to do what you want, I wouldn't use the DataFrame plotting methods. I'm also a former experimental physicist, and based on experience with ROOT I think that the Python analog you want is best accomplished using matplotlib.  In matplotlib.pyplot there is a method, hist2d(), which will give you the kind of heat map you're looking for.

As for creating the dataframe, an easy way to do it is:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
```